# Hadoop Data Nodes based on Data Size

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to estimate the resources based on the data size.
Is there a thumb rule for deciding the number of required data nodes based on the data size?

Answer (score 0):

No not really. Usually in a typical Hadoop cluster, there is one DataNode per node.
Sorry for the short answer but thats it! :)
Just keep in mind that Hadoop prefers to deal with a small number of huge files.

Comment: then is there a way to estimate number of nodes in a cluster with 15 TB data?

Comment: @Seenu Have a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/scalability-hadoop-distributed-file-system-452.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that data (by default) is replicated 3 times (original copy + 2 more).  That is, if you have 15TB of data, you will need at least 45TB of disk space to accommodate for the replicas.

Replicas cannot be on the same node, so you would need at least 3 Datanodes with 15TB of storage, assuming default configuration.